# Memcache with MAMP and PHP 5.3 on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, memcached, mamp

I would like to install the PHP Memcache extension to my MAMP server (v1.9.1 with PHP 5.3.2). To do this I've followed the steps in the installation instruction here: http://www.lullabot.com/articles/setup-memcached-mamp-sandbox-environment

When running `./pecl i memcache` it results in an error:

> ./pecl: line 28: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php: Permission denied
>
> ./pecl: line 28: exec: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php: cannot execute: Unknown error: 0

Running `sudo ./pecl i memcache` doesn't work, too. Did you have the same trouble and how did you solve it?

I have not installed Xcode, or should I do?

Best Regards,
Jim

Comment: I know that a lot of the tutorials/blogs I've tried did not work. I found this one here and when I followed the directions exactly, it finally worked! I wanted to rip my eyes out I spent so long trying to figure it out. Anyway here's the link: http://delexxi.com/blog/post/1/Setup-Memcache-on-MAMP-19

Comment: This link helped me set up the php5.3 memcached extension on Mac OSX
http://www.re-cycledair.com/installing-memcache-on-mamp

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't installed Xcode, then you can't compile c programs. More specifically, you need to install the Unix development tools package from Xcode. Which I am actually do at this moment. I had Xcode installed, but not the Unix development tools.

I'm following the instructions from here to install memcache and PHP.
http://www.glenscott.co.uk/blog/2009/08/30/install-memcached-php-extension-on-os-x-snow-leopard/

Answer (score 0):

Right now what helped me was this GitHub project: https://github.com/majksner/php-memcached-mamp

In its README you can find instructions about dependencies, which can be installed using homebrew.